# jQuery Mobile - Intellisense for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, jquery-mobile, intellisense

I have been unable to get Visual Studio to present intellisense when working with jQuery-Mobil.

How do I enable this in Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [intellisense-jquery-mobile](https://github.com/hakanson/intellisense-jquery-mobile#readme) that adds Intellisense support to Visual Studio 2010 SP1 for the jQuery Mobile data-* attributes.

To install, copy the html_5_jqm.xsd to the appropriate Visual Studio schema directory (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html) and execute the corresponding .reg file for your environment.

Answer (score 0):

So I did everything except "running the corresponding .reg for my environment".
I cannot understand how to do this.Inside of Windows or in VS.I am using VS 2010 SP1.