# jQuery mobile tools for vs2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jquery-mobile, mobile

Which tools and addins are good to develop Jquery mobile tools in VS2010?

Tools may be addins, nu packages or other tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQM Is still growing so I'm sure more tools will come.

Would these be of any help for you?

- https://github.com/hakanson/intellisense-jquery-mobile
- http://appendto.com/community/jquery-vsdoc

Related:

- [jQuery Mobile - Intellisense for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580574/jquery-mobile-intellisence-for-visual-studio-2010)